# -[RTIInputSystemClient remoteTextInputSessionWithID:performInputOperation:] perform input operation requires a valid sessionID Error in Xcode SwiftUI

Tags: xcode, swiftui, firebase-authentication

When I enter email and password information in my Login screen and tap either "Log in" or "Create Account" I get this message in my app [error message in app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRx7J.jpg) and in my console I am receiving this message:

`-[RTIInputSystemClient remoteTextInputSessionWithID:performInputOperation:] perform input operation requires a valid sessionID`

I have tried searching various forums on StackOverflow and Apple Developer forums but I have not seen any solution posted.

1. Authentication View that is called after the RootView(), this is where the error is occurring

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct IdentifiableError: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let message: String
}

struct AuthView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: JobApplicationViewModel
    @State private var email: String = ""
    @State private var password: String = ""
    @State private var storedEmail: String = "" // Separate variable to hold the email
    @State private var storedPassword: String = "" // Separate variable to hold the password
    @State private var showingLogin = false
    @State private var showingCreateAccount = false
    @State private var identifiableError: IdentifiableError?
    @FocusState private var isInputActive: Bool // For iOS 15+

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "briefcase.fill")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
                .padding()

            Text("Welcome to Job Tracker Pro")
                .font(.largeTitle)

            TextField("Email", text: $email)
                .autocapitalization(.none)
                .keyboardType(.emailAddress)
                .disableAutocorrection(true)
                .padding()
                .border(Color.gray)
                .onChange(of: email) { [email] in
                    storedEmail = email
                }
                .onSubmit {
                    storedEmail = email // Store the email when submit the field
                }
            
            SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                .padding()
                .border(Color.gray)
                .onChange(of: password) { [password] in
                    storedPassword = password
                }
                .onSubmit {
                    storedPassword = password // Store the password when submit the field
                }
            
            Button("Log In") {
                hideKeyboard() // Dismiss the keyboard
                // Use storedEmail and storedPassword to log in
                // If you're handling login directly in AuthView
                viewModel.logIn(email: storedEmail, password: storedPassword) { success, message in
                    // Handle completion
                }

                showingLogin = true
            }
            .padding()

            Button("Create Account") {
                hideKeyboard() // Dismiss the keyboard
                // Use storedEmail and storedPassword to create an account
                // If you're handling account creation directly in AuthView
                viewModel.createAccount(email: storedEmail, password: storedPassword) {    success, message in
                        // Handle completion
                }
                
                showingCreateAccount = true
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .alert(item: $identifiableError) { error in
            Alert(
                title: Text("Error"),
                message: Text(error.message),
                dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")) {
                    identifiableError = nil
                }
            )
        }
        .onReceive(viewModel.$error) { error in
            if let error = error {
                identifiableError = IdentifiableError(message: error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}

#if canImport(UIKit)
extension View {
    func hideKeyboard() {
        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
    }
}
#endif
```

Please reply back if you have any insight on what might be causing this or if you have any questions about the code or any other views, view models, or models that I have implemented.

Comment: May not be related, but what happens if `UIKit`
 cannot be imported, you still call `hideKeyboard()` in your Buttons.
 Try wrapping `#if canImport(UIKit)` around the
 `UIApplication.shared....` not the `extension View`

Comment: it is caused by the FocusState on iOS 17. Gotta wait for Apple I guess.